# Change Sharepoint Default Calendar to a shared Outlook Calendar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, calendar, outlook

Is it possible to point the calendar built into sharepoint to a shared outlook calendar? I know I could just export the outlook calendar and then import it into the sharepoint calendar, but the client wants to just update the shared outlook calendar and not the sharepoint one (even though it is already synced to their computer). Let me know if you need more details and thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your looking for: https://experts.missouristate.edu/display/csvhelpdesk/Adding+a+SharePoint+Calendar+to+Outlook

and

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-and-update-a-sharepoint-calendar-HA010081987.aspx#BM2

hope this helps!